# How do I multiply a matrix and a column vector of variables in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, type-conversion, matrix-multiplication, ode45

I have a matrix 'F' (3 * 20 double) and a cell-type 'ans' (20*1) consisting of variables of the form (1,x,y,z,xy,yx,...). I wanted to multiply F and ans to get a system of equations and use that to get the function

```
f = @(t,y) F * ans
```

which I will later use to solve ODEs. This gives me the error

```
Operator '*' is not supported for operands of type 'cell'.
```

Now, I am unable to convert celltype to type double. If I write

```
var = str2double(ans)
```

then var is simply consisting of NaN instead of the variables. Can someone please help?

Comment: Please read [mre], then [edit] your post accordingly. As it stands, it’s impossible to help you because it’s unclear what `ans` is.

Answer (score 0):

1. Do not use `ans` as a variable name. It is the default output variable if no other is specified. This is almost guaranteed to create problems. Save it as something else.
2. `cell` is not a string. Cells are "containers" that can store whatever information you want, numbers, strings, structs, cells or even function handles.

If your cell contains numeric values, then you must convert it to a numeric matrix. There are many ways to do this, but the most intuitive way is simply using [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html).

This will only work if each of your cells contain the same number of columns, and all cells contain only numeric data.

Comment: I am actually not storing my values in ans. It is the output of a function (let's call it List_Poly) that I am using. So ans is something of the form (1, x, y, xy, xz, yz, xyz, ) and this varies as we pass different values to List_Poly. Also, this doesn't contain numeric values. All of these (except for the constant: 1) are variables that will make up a polynomial equation.

Comment: 1. Then you should do `some_variable_name = List_Poly(input_variables)`. What do you mean by variables? `syms`? Is `xy = x*y`? Do all cells contain a single value? Can you show the exact output (`celldisp`)? What form is that polynomial equation? What exactly do you expect to get out?

Comment: Is the output of List_Poly a cell array of strings? A vector of symbolic variables? Or ...?